# Table View Cell renders incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a table view using custom table view cell using data from the NSSArray property of the controller class. when i ran the app only the first row of the table view display correctly.

```c
#import "MainTableViewController.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* items;
@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _items = @[@"Item1", @"Item2", @"Item3"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _items.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell* tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];

    if (!tableViewCell) {
        UINib* tableViewCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil];
        [tableView registerNib:tableViewCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
        tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
    }

    return tableViewCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CalculatorViewController* calculatorViewController = [[CalculatorViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:calculatorViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(TableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.label.text = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

the first row renders Item1 but the rest only renders the first two character and dots for each row. ex It... for row 2 and the rest. the expected result is it displays everything in the _items array.

Comment: Why don't you put this cell.label.text = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; at cellForRowArIndexPath method

Comment: it could renders incorrectly when some events happen

Comment: Agreed, you need to populate the cell contents in cellForRowAtIndexPath, not in willDisplayCell.  Please describe how it "renders incorrectly when some events happen" and maybe we can help you solve that problem.